# Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, Charges, value = numeric(0)) : replacement has 0 rows, data has 1338

Tags: r

```r
data$Charges <- as.numeric(gsub(",", "", data$Charges))
Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, Charges, value = numeric(0)) : 
  replacement has 0 rows, data has 1338
```

I wanted to Ensure Charges ( a column in a dataset ) is numeric before Split the charges data into two categories

Comment: Is your first paragraph entirely an error message or is there code in there?

Comment: A [example] would help us to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would seem that `as.numeric(gsub(",", "", data$Charges))` returns nothing, hence 0 rows. The only way I managed to make your code return numeric(0) is by having 1 NULL, a list of NULLs would still returns NAs.

So I will guess that this is because the column you are referencing doesn't exist.

The 'replacement' part of the message could be confusing because you think you are replacing the columns value, but you get the same error when assigning a new column with no values (what is most likely happening here)

Example of the behavior :

```
> df <- data.frame(a = letters)
> df$b <- as.numeric(df$b)
Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, b, value = numeric(0)) : 
  replacement has 0 rows, data has 26
```